# mongo db - IllegalStateException - state should be open

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have two applications. one of them is spring boot and other is spring java application. The call goes from springboot application to the java application and performs some action.
I am using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-3.0.0 and connecting to mongo through configuring in properties.
For java application, its configured in xml

```
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" connection-string="${MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING}"/>
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" >
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
  
  <!-- bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/> -->
  <mongo:repositories base-package="edu.illinois.techservices.cloudbroker.core.repository" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate" />
  <context:annotation-config />
```

At some point, the application is throwing:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open
at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:79)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:165)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AbstractMultiServerCluster.getDescription(AbstractMultiServerCluster.java:50)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:144)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:101)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:291)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:183)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:135)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2968)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2692)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.doFind(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:220)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.oneValue(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:132)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.lambda$getExecution$6(AbstractMongoQuery.java:188)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.doExecute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:152)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:127)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:160)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.findByName(Unknown Source)

It looks like spring boot is resetting the connection some where? I am not able to figure out where and how this is happening.

Thanks,
Pbale